# Validating a form with JavaScript and displaying them on the page rather than an alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've created a form, that I need to validate with JavaScript or using Jquery. How would I validate if the dropdown list has the value "Title" and if the text box is empty and display it on the page rather then an alert box :

```
       <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="myForm">
       <option value="Title" id="title_3-0"  disabled selected>Title</option><option  value="Mr" id="title_3-1">Mr</option>
 <option value="Mrs" id="title_3-2">Mrs</option><option value="Miss" id="title_3- 3">Miss</option>
 <option value="Ms" id="title_3-4">Ms</option><option value="Dr" id="title_3-5">Dr</option>
 <option value="Professor" id="title_3-6">Professor</option></select></div></div>
```

TextBox:

```
    <input type="text" class="text" name="firstname_4" id="amf-input-firstname_4" value="" placeholder="First Name">
```

I also have a button.

Comment: So the question is, How do you put a message on the page itself instead of having an alert box pop up?

Comment: Yes, I'm new to Javascript. The message could appear in a div as a summary or under each control.

Comment: This isn't a JavaScript issue (or at least, it isn't *only* a JavaScript issue). You have to design the message you want as part of HTML, then make those elements hidden using CSS `display: none` on that element. Then, show or hide the error message dynamically (that part is JavaScript). But the first step is getting the HTML and CSS the way you want it to look when an error occurs.

Comment: @user3120015, You are absolutely correct. You can do so by adding a div element in your html with an id (lets say id="testing"). Then from javascript you can call `document.getElementById('testing').innerHTML = "Text that you want to put";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
  var return_value = true;
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["firstname_4"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "First name must be filled out<br />";
    return_value = false;
  }
  var y=document.forms["myForm"]["selectid"];
  if(y.options[y.selectedIndex].value == "Title")
  {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "You need to select a title<br />";
    return_value = false;
  }
  return return_value;
}
</script>


<span id="error"></span>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" class="text" name="firstname_4" id="amf-input-firstname_4" value="" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you like, you can also put an "error span element" above/beneath each field and set each error individually:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
  var return_value = true;
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["firstname_4"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "First name must be filled out";
    return_value = false;
  }
  var y=document.forms["myForm"]["selectid"];
  if(y.options[y.selectedIndex].value == "Title")
  {
    document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "You need to select a title";
    return_value = false;
  }
  return return_value;
}
</script>


<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

First name: <input type="text" class="text" name="firstname_4" id="amf-input-firstname_4" value="" placeholder="First Name">
<span id="error1"></span>

Title: <input .... >
<span id="error2"></span>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How do i get them to validate at the same time, as it's only doing the first if statement?

Comment: I updated my answer with one way how it can be done. The trick is to put the `return true/false` at the end of your method.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<select id="ddl"> <option value="Title" id="title_3-0" selected>Title</option><option  value="Mr" id="title_3-1">Mr</option>
 <option value="Mrs" id="title_3-2">Mrs</option><option value="Miss" id="title_3- 3">Miss</option>
 <option value="Ms" id="title_3-4">Ms</option><option value="Dr" id="title_3-5">Dr</option>
 <option value="Professor" id="title_3-6">Professor</option></select>

<input type="text" class="text" name="firstname_4" id="amf-input-firstname_4" value="" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn"/>
    <span id="error"/>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#btn').click(function (){
        if(($('#amf-input-firstname_4').val()=='') || ($("#ddl :selected").val() == 'Title'))
    {  
        $('#error').html('Please select title and enter name.');
    }
    else
    {
       $('#error').html('Success'); 
    }
    return false;
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/8h8HF/